# Cannot uninstall SQL Server 2008 from Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: virtualbox, debian, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2

I have install SQL Server 2008(64-bit) express on the virtualbox in virtual machine, with guest os Windows Server 2012 R2(It is also domain controller). After the installation, I decide I would like to uninstall this SQL Server and install another version of the SQL Server. Every time I go to the Program and Features, to uninstall them the Virtual Machine closing. I would like your help to guide me, how to solve my problem?

My Host OS is: Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)
My Virtual Box version is: 4.3.20 r96996

The closing happens : on the Removal Progress of the SQL Server Uninstall.

I also stop every service, which have related name with SQL Server, before the uninstall.

Here you can see the freezing time:

[image]

Here is also my VBox log:
[VBox.log](http://pastebin.com/52jcvQWe)

Here is the [C:\Temp\sqlredist_uninstall.log](http://pastebin.com/AtNUswsp) .

Thanks for your attention and time

Comment: Is there anything regarding the shutdown reported in the Event Logs of the guest? Any VirtualBox logs on the host? What OS is the host? Which version of VirtualBox are you using? etc...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 thanks for your response, where I can find the Event Logs of the guest. And I will edit my question.

Comment: The Event Logs are a basic part of Windows, try using Window 2012's inbuilt search to locate them, or (gasp) check Windows' online help: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/open-event-viewer. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was my problem! The USB Hard Disk, which a have connected on the VM, cause all the problems on the VM. I remove it and everything, works fine. The uninstall of SQL Server was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Restore SQL-DMO

```
regsvr32.exe sqldmo.dll
```

Uninstall SQL Server component:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\ARPWrapper.exe /Remove
```

Install/Uninstall SQL Server log:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\
```

In SQL Server Express folder run:

```
Setup.exe /Action=Uninstall /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /FEATURES=SQL,RS /Q
```

or use `/QUIET`

var 2:

```
start /wait msiexec /x {SQL Server CLSID} SKIPREDISTPREREQS=1 /l*v C:\Temp\sqlredist_uninstall.log
```

var 3:

```
MsiExec.exe /I {SQL Server CLSID}
```

var 4:

[How to uninstall an instance of SQL Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955404)

Comment: And this will stop the computer from suddenly turning off because...?

Comment: I will test it tomorrow and I will come back with the results. Thanks @STTR

Comment: @KostasC add log at `Setup Bootstrap\Log` if possible.

Comment: This command:
`Setup.exe /Action=Uninstall /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /FEATURES=SQL,RS /Q` also crash the VM.

Comment: This command: `start /wait msiexec /x {SQL Server CLSID} SKIPREDISTPREREQS=1 /l*v C:\Temp\sqlredist_uninstall.log` also crash the VM.

Comment: @KostasC VirtualBox? Use 4.12 version, other new version - unstable. Search CLSID SQL Server Express in registry and replace `{SQL Server CLSID}`